# Navigation Architecture Component - Action Navigation with lambda expression

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have added a new action `Navigation.xml`:

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/launcher_home"
    android:name="com.example.android.codelabs.navigation.MainFragment"
    android:label="@string/home"
    tools:layout="@layout/main_fragment">
    <action
        android:id="@+id/go_to_step_one"
        app:destination="@id/flow_step_one" />
</fragment>
```

When calling the navigation action, if i use, the navigation works correctly :

```
 view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigate_action_bt)?.setOnClickListener(
            Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.go_to_step_one, null)
    )
```

But when calling it with a lambda, it does not work :

```
 view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigate_action_bt)?.setOnClickListener {
        Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.go_to_step_one, null)
    }
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Well, that's the proper way of working. The method `Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener()` [returns](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/navigation/Navigation) a `View.OnClickListener` and according to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#java) the proper way of assiging it is by using, even in Kotlin:

```
button.setOnClickListener(Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.next_fragment, null));
```

If you using the method inside the lambda, the lambda itself is the click listener so you're returning a click listener inside the click listener, that's why it isn't working. It's like doing this:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
            View.OnClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this, "hi", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        }
```

What you might be intrested in is this:

```
 view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigate_action_bt)?.setOnClickListener { view ->
   view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.go_to_step_one)
}
```

Which will perform the navigation transition on button click.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the brackets after
`.setOnClickListener`with parentheses

```
 view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigate_action_bt)?.setOnClickListener {
    Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.go_to_step_one, null)
}

 view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigate_action_bt)?.setOnClickListener(
    Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.go_to_step_one, null)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it almost right. The only thing missing is to call 'onClick' method. Let me add my working block of code here.

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
    when(v) {
        dashboardButton -> Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToDashboardFragment()).onClick(v)
        registerButton -> Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginFragmentToRegisterFragment()).onClick(v)
    }
}
```

In your code, you should make a change like this.

```
 view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.navigate_action_bt)?.setOnClickListener {
    Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.go_to_step_one, null).onClick(view)
}
```